# Always based on clock And one of inputs change

Tags: verilog, clock

I have a module `m(in1,in2,in3,in4,out1,out2);`
I need to implement it in such a way that in each `positive clock edge` :
if `in1 or in2` are changed the output `out1` is assigned as `in1+in2`
if `in3 or in4` are changed the output `out2` is assigned as `in3*in4`
How to implement that in verilog?

```
always @(posedge clk and(in1 or in2))
begin 
out1 = in1 + in2;
end

always @(posedge clk and (in3 or in4))
begin 
out2 = in3 * in4;
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to store what in1 to in4 were from the previous clock positive edge in order to determine if they have changed on the current clock edge?

Comment: I don`t think that I need to.Since the definition of always is "the sensitivity list is satisfied" and  don`t need to care if sensitivity list has changed.In the simple example :1 always @ ( A or B ) begin
2 C = A & B ;
3 end
Program  species that when A or B change values, update the value of C

Comment: If A or B doesn't change, then the new value of C will be the same as it was before, so the effect is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement is ambiguous. First of all, your module doesn't show a `clk` input, so where does that come from? Also, do `in1` through `in4` meet setup and hold requirements with respect to this clock?

In any case, the obvious way to code what you describe would be like this:

```
module (
  input clk,
  input in1,
  input in2,
  input in3,
  input in4,
  output out1,
  output out2
);

  reg in1_a, in2_a, in3_a, in4_a;

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    in1_a <= in1;
    in2_a <= in2;
    in3_a <= in3;
    in4_a <= in4;
  end

  assign out1 = in1_a + in2_a;
  assign out2 = in3_a * in4_a;

endmodule
```

With this setup, the input registers only change if the inputs have changed since the previous clock edge, and the outputs (and the logic driving them) only change if the corresponding input registers change.

Comment: Wah, why code it like this? This has double the registers of Greg's code, and the outputs aren't registered like his are.

Answer (score 4):

Greg gives the usual way to perform the function you're asking for:

```
always @(posedge clk)
  begin 
    out1 <= in1 + in2;
    out2 <= in3 * in4;
end
```

The question now is, why do people do it this way and not the way you came up with?

First, remember that Verilog is meant to describe hardware. It doesn't give a sequence of steps to be executed one after the other like an ordinary computer programming language does. What the code above describes is something like this:

[image]

Despite not including `in1` and `in2` on the sensitivity list, in fact what happens is every time either of those signals changes, the adder portion of the circuit will change its value. However the named output signal `out1` only changes its value when the `posedge clk` event occurs.

Due to the way the elements work in CMOS logic, very little power is consumed in this circuit unless one of the inputs changes. So there's no need to worry about minimizing unnecessary operations on that account.

Now lets look at your suggested version:

```
always @(posedge clk and(in1 or in2))
  begin 
    out1 = in1 + in2;
  end
```

Logically, this is asking not to change the outputs unless a `posedge clk` event occuts at exactly the same time as either an `in1` or an `in2` event. What constitutes "exactly the same time" would have to be defined by a quirk of your simulator (it would mean the events happen in exactly the same simulation time step), or your hardware (the ability of some circuit to distinguish a small increment of time). As such it would be very hard for the simulator to predict the output of the synthesized logic, and so wouldn't be a coding style I'd recommend.

What you really probably want to do is wait for an `in1` or `in2` event, then wait for a clock edge. This can, in fact, be coded:

```
always @(in1 or in2)
  begin
    @(posedge clk);
    out1 <= in1 + in2;
  end
```

However it is not likely to synthesize, because its not obvious what kind of circuit could ignore further changes in `in1` and `in2` while waiting for the clock edge (some kind of latch, maybe?) If you assume `in1` and `in2` don't change more than once per clock cycle, then the output will be identical to the usual way (Greg's code).

Answer (score 2):

Your using a clocking event, therefore there is no reason to have the inputs in the sensitivity list. It doesn't matter if the the inputs change or not. At every posedge clock, assign the outputs.

```
always @(posedge clk)
  begin 
    out1 <= in1 + in2;
    out2 <= in3 * in4;
  end
```

Comment: The restriction I have is : don`t perform operations without need.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid performing unneeded operations? Is it to save power or to make the design faster? If it's the second one, hardware design doesn't work that way so don't worry about it. If it's the first, then you need to design at a lower level. You need to make an adder block with an enable pin, then control that enable pin to determine whether the operation is done or not. But there's a good chance it won't end up saving you power overall anyway (due to not using optimized adder blocks, increased area, ...).

Comment: Digital power is very closely linked to the toggles, if the inputs do not change nothing toggles, which results in low power.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clock gater that meets the requirements. That said, a better approach may be to save previous values of all inputs and compare them to new values, and then AND the result with the clk.

```
  reg out1_sense;
  reg out2_sense;
  wire out1_clk;
  wire out2_clk;

  always @(in1 or in2) begin
    out1_sense <= 1'b1;
  end
  assign out1_clk = clk & out1_sense;

  always @(in3 or in4) begin
    out2_sense <= 1'b1;
  end
  assign out2_clk = clk & out2_sense;

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    out1_sense <= 1'b0;
    out2_sense <= 1'b0;
  end

  always @(posedge out1_clk) begin 
    out1 = in1 + in2;
  end

  always @(posedge out2_clk) begin 
    out2 = in3 * in4;
  end
```

Compiled design and test at EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/51

Comment: You assign to `out1_sense` (and others) in more than one always block. Have you tried to synthesize this?

Comment: Even if this code was synthesize-able, a glitch will happen if any `in*` changes while clock is high.